# Sidebar cut off at the bottom when scrolling vertically

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

With the following Tailwind CSS, if you scroll down, you'll see that the sidebar has been cut off at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sidebar Example</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="flex">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="h-screen w-64 border-r border-gray-200 bg-white p-4">
        <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold">Sidebar</h1>
        <ul class="mt-4">
            <!-- Manually added list items for demonstration -->
            <li class="py-2">Item 1</li>
            <li class="py-2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="py-2">Item 3</li>
            <!-- Add more items as needed -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="flex-1 p-8" style="min-height: 200vh;">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold">Main Content</h2>
        <p>This is the main content area.</p>
        <!-- Additional content here -->
        <p>Scroll down to see more content...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

How to prevent that?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/MWRgrrP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `h-screen` to `min-h-screen` resolve your issue

`min-h-screen`: min-height: 100vh;

```js
document.body.classList.add('bg-blue-700');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sidebar Example</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="flex">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="min-h-screen w-64 border-r border-gray-200 bg-white p-4">
        <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold">Sidebar</h1>
        <ul class="mt-4">
            <!-- Manually added list items for demonstration -->
            <li class="py-2">Item 1</li>
            <li class="py-2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="py-2">Item 3</li>
            <!-- Add more items as needed -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="flex-1 p-8" style="min-height: 200vh;">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold">Main Content</h2>
        <p>This is the main content area.</p>
        <!-- Additional content here -->
        <p>Scroll down to see more content...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost ... the sidebar will be cut off if the main content items don't occupy the whole screen vertically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is8CS.png. I think you'll see that if you remove `min-height: 200vh;`

Comment: I edited the answer, it may work now

Comment: Awesome! How come you only have 11 of reputation? I guess `min-h-screen` is acting as `h-auto` and `h-screen` together?

Comment: yeah, you're right. The `min-height` property defines the minimum height of an element. If the content is smaller than the minimum height, the minimum height will be applied. If the content is larger than the minimum height, the `min-height` property has no effect and the height will be [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#formal_definition) which is `auto`

Comment: @wyc my primary SO account was temporarily suspended